# Why doesn't Markitup BBcode preview work for me?

Tags: java, jquery, preview, markitup

I dont know how to make the BBcode preview on Markitup Editor work.

I followed all instructions and the editor is working. I really dont understand what to do to make the correct preview appear. I can open the windows preview but I cant get the html code.

I had downloaded the parser file (markitup.bbcode.parser.php) and settled the `previewParserPath` too and I read about configuring or creating a file called `preview.php` but really I dont know how to do it.

Can anyone help?

**Update:**

[@marco](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829062/why-doesnt-markitup-bbcode-preview-work-for-me/2942625#2942625) this works great

And I think it is not bug. The file is just a parser. I think I'm missing some tutorial in markitup page i.e. how to install it

Comment: How about some code and where in the installation process (http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/documentation/) you get stuck after debugging?

Answer (score 2):

open the parser.php file
it contains only a function, doesn't it?
so, without any echo, how does it can work?
maybe it's a bug i don't know.

so, add the follow string wherever you want:

```
echo BBCode2Html( $_POST['data'] );
```

Comment: What do you mean "Where ever you want"?

Comment: exscuse my english.
you can add that row where you want, into the parser.php file.

Answer (score 0):

[Merged this update by OP into question]